# Rename a file extension by using otherwise in specified

Tags: python-2.7, path, subprocess, glob, chdir

I have many files with a specific extension in a folder and what I want is to change their extension ( associated with a particular executable program for those files )

```
import glob, os, shutil, os, errno, sys
import subprocess
from glob import glob
from os import getcwd
from os.path import join
from os.path import basename
from subprocess import call

camino = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Dats\\COX\\' 
listado = glob(join(camino,'D*','20*','B*','1*'))

for archivo in listado:
    tmp = os.path.split(archivo)
    path = tmp[0]
    log = archivo
    estacion = os.path.basename(tmp[0])

    try:
        print (path)
        os.chdir(path)
        subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Dats\\rt_mseed.exe', log])

    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
             print ('error')
        else:
             print ('Error: %s' % e)
```

I have this advanced code, when run it displays this error.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\python listado.py
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014322\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014323\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014324\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014325\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Dats\COX\DISK1\2014326\B088
Error: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Well, it sounds like those files don't exist.

Comment: unrelated: pass `cwd=path` instead of `os.chdir(path)` (note: it won't make non-existing directories to appear)